# Filemaker if statement won't work

Tags: parsing, if-statement, iteration, filemaker

I have an if statement that is iterating through json data successfully but for some reason my if statement always reads as true when that shouldn't be the case. The result of this is the rest of my if statement isn't carried out so the data that I need to go to other fields is being reinserted in the same field rather than progressing to the next one.

Here is my code.

```
Set Variable [ $dataCount; Value:ValueCount ( JSONListKeys ( $json ; "data" ) ) ]
Set Variable [ $i; Value:0 ]
#needs if statement to revert changes if existing
Go to Layout [ “grievances” (grievances) ]
New Record/Request
Set Field [ grievances::_IDgrievance; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "id" ) ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceTimestampSubmitted; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "timestamp" ) ]
Loop
#match institution
Set Error Capture [ On ]
If [ (JSONGetElement ( $json ; GetAsNumber ( "data[" & $i & "].field") ) = GetField ( jsonFieldIDs::institution )) ]
Set Field [ grievances::institution; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].value" ) ]
#match delegate
Else If [ (JSONGetElement ( $json ; GetAsNumber ( "data[" & $i & "].field" )) = GetAsNumber (jsonFieldIDs::delegates)) = 1 ]
Set Field [ grievances::delegate; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].value" ) ]
#match grievancedateorignated
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::dateGrievanceOriginated ]
Set Field [ grievances::dateGrievanceOriginated; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match grievanceStep
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::grievanceStep ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceStep; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match relatedgrievanceID
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::grievanceSubmissionID ]
Set Field [ grievances::relatedGrievance; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesName
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::employeesName ]
Set Field [ grievances::rawEmployeeName; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesPhoneNumber
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::employeePhone ]
Set Field [ grievances::rawEmployeePhoneNumber; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesAddress
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::employeesAddress ]
Set Field [ grievances::rawEmployeeAddress; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesEmail
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::email ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesEmail; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesJobTitle
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::delegates ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesJobTitle; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesShift
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::shift ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesShift; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesSeniorityDate
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::seniorityDate ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesSeniorityDate; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match Employee Department
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::department ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesDepartment; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match EmployeesSignature
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::employeeSignature ]
Set Field [ grievances::employeesSignature; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match nature of grievance
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::natureOfGrievance ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceNature; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match violation of Article
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::violationOfArticle ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceArticle; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match grievanceSection
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::section ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceSection; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match grievance Statement of Case
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::statementOfCase ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceCaseStatement; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match grievance Adjustment Requested
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::adjustmentRequested ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceAdjustmentRequested; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
#match Union Rep or Delegate Signature
Else If [ JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" ) = jsonFieldIDs::unionDelegateUnionRepSignature ]
Set Field [ grievances::grievanceUnionRepSignature; JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "]value" ) ]
End If
Set Variable [ $i; Value:$i + 1 ]
Exit Loop If [ $i ≥ $dataCount ]
End Loop
Commit Records/Requests [ No dialog ]
Go to Layout [ original layout ]
```

The script works but why is my if statement reading as true?

**UPDATE**

I've attached the json

```
{
  "id": "383694318",
  "timestamp": "2018",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
  "remote_addr": "",
  "payment_status": "",
  "form": "",
  "latitude": "",
  "longitude": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "field": "59492998",
      "value": "institution name"
    },
    {
      "field": "61085927",
      "value": "delegate name"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493162",
      "value": "Jan 02, 2016"
    },
    {
      "field": "60868658",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493345",
      "value": "first = jane\nmiddle = a\nlast = doe"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493496",
      "value": "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493502",
      "value": "email@address.com"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493355",
      "value": "CNA"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493364",
      "value": "1st Shift"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493381",
      "value": "Dec xx, 19xx"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493506",
      "value": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.formstack.com/uploads/.png"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493533",
      "value": "wrongful termination"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493536",
      "value": "33-1"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493577",
      "value": "XIII"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493589",
      "value": "Wrongful Termination "
    },
    {
      "field": "59493591",
      "value": "make whole"
    },
    {
      "field": "59493713",
      "value": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.formstack.com/uploads/.png"
    }
  ],
  "pretty_field_id": "59493345"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `jsonFieldIDs::institution` returns a field name, `GetField()` is going to return the content of the field, not the name.

Without having the file/json to review, it is a little hard to troubleshoot.

Also, try turning error capture off and see if you get any errors.

***UPDATE***

In the first if statement, your are using GetAsNumber on the json key, not the result:

If [ (JSONGetElement ( $json ; **GetAsNumber** ( "data[" & $i & "].field") ) = GetField ( jsonFieldIDs::institution )) ]

It should be outside `JSONGetElement`

If [ ( **GetAsNumber**(JSONGetElement ( $json ; "data[" & $i & "].field" )) = GetField ( jsonFieldIDs::institution )) ]

Also, I would remove `GetField` since you are passing the field directly.

Comment: My jsonFieldIDs table includes all of the field names within the json. I should be getting contents of the field because it contains the numeric value that identifies which field is which (i think, i'm trying to understand what you mean). I tired turning off error capture and I still get errors.

Comment: Jason is right. Read up on GetField to understand how it works. It involves indirection. I suspect you don´t want to use it in this way. Try the statement without GetField. Also, try each statement in the Data Viewer to see what you get (if you don’t have the Developer Assistant that can evaluate anything on the spot).

Comment: I tried the statement without the GetField i'm still getting the issue of the if statement reading as always true.

Comment: Is it the first if statement, or one of the others?